# fresh re installation of ckan, jetty, solr

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies, software-uninstall

I am trying to install ckan on my ubuntu 14.04, but i got into some errors that i cant fix, so i decided to do a fresh installation after i remove everything from my computer. I am getting some errors while i try to sudo apt-get remove jetty i get

```
*Stopping Jetty servlet engine (was reachable on http://myComputer-ubuntu:8983/).

jetty start-stop-daemon: user 'solr' not found

start-stop-daemon: user 'solr' not found

invoke-rc.d: initscript jetty, action "stop" failed.

dpkg: error processing package jetty (--remove): subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2

*Starting Jetty servlet engine. jetty start-stop-daemon: user 'solr' not found *(already running). [ OK ]

Errors were encountered while processing:

jetty

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

after doing sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove jetty I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
jetty : Depends: libjetty-java (>= 6.1.26-1ubuntu1.1) but it is not installed

Depends: jsvc but it is not installed

Depends: apache2-utils How on earth can i completely remove Jetty!!??!!
```

could any one have an idea? Thanks

(also posted on StackOverflow, but this seems like the proper place for it)

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jetty/+bug/1021193. If it's still affecting you, you could log on and vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

You just edit the jetty startup script `/etc/init.d/jetty` I assume,  and put a clean exit on the 2nd line:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
exit 0
```

then

```
apt-get update && apt-get -f install
```

And that will cleanly remove jetty.  it fails because the init script fails.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same error messages on Ubuntu 14 and I've just figured out what it was.

The issue was with the line endings of `/etc/default/jetty`. It turned out that the file had been edited on Windows and had line endings of `CRLF`, once I updated the file to `LF` and re-ran it the issue was solved.

The quickest way to test this is to revert back to Jetty's original config by running `sudo mv /etc/default/jetty /tmp/` and then run `sudo service jetty restart`. If you have the same issue as me, jetty will restart properly.